# what is jat file found in flash web games?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flashdevelop

I found many .jat files when i analyse a flash web game with firebug. It maybe a user model.But I don't know how does it make?

Comment: do you mean `.jar`? How do you analyze it? Where do you found the files? Can you open them (with a text editor or a zip application)?

Comment: It isn't .jar.It looks like a 3D UserModel file which made by flash.

Comment: maybe part of a specific 3D-framework?

Comment: I guess it is.  But I don't know which framework

Comment: I think it's not Away3D, Sandy or Papervision. What about asking the developer of the game? ;)

Comment: Thank you. It maybe Core Technology of that company.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL you are analyzing? That would probably help diagnose this.